# ASP.net web page update issue ( Postback?)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Greeting of the day everyone.

Hoping you are all well. I need your help to solve a simple issue ( I an new to C# + ASP.net).

I have created a ASp.net portal. When a user open that portal (web page). the Webpage give him a list of Groups whose he is the member of and the list of group whose he can add to himself..

It also contain two Drop Downs. One contains the list of groups, whose use can add to themselves. The second one contains the list of groups , whose the user is member of, and he can remove it from those groups.

Adding and removing code is working fine. But I have to refresh the page manually to show the updated information. After clicking the Add or Remove Button page is not refreshing with the updated information.

I tried to use redirected to main [image]page using `Response.Redirect("Success.aspx")`

But nothing working,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string uN = "domain\\michael.jackson";
    //SystemResources sr = new SystemResources();
    //ActiveUser usr = sr.GetUserDetails(uN).FirstOrDefault();

    LabelUserName.Text = "michael.jackson";

    // Getting the list of groups using of praticular OU the classOrgUnitGroup

    string sdomain = ClassGroupPortalSettings.getDomainName();
    string sInterstOU = "OU=testing,DC=analysys,DC=com";
    classOrgUnitGroup a = new classOrgUnitGroup();
    List<string> allGroups = a.GetGroupFromOu(sdomain, sInterstOU);
    string grouplist = "<ul>";
    foreach (string group in allGroups)
    {
        grouplist = grouplist + "<li><a href='showgroupmembers.aspx?group=" + group + "'>" + group + "</a></li>";

    }

    grouplist = grouplist + "</ul>";
    lblOpenGroups.Text = grouplist;

    //// 4. Finding users group membership.
    string sDomain = ClassGroupPortalSettings.getDomainName();
    classUserGroupMembership myMembership = new classUserGroupMembership();
    List<string> myGroupsMem = myMembership.getMyGroupMembership(sDomain, "domain\\michael.jackson");

    string glList = "<ul>";
    string openlList = "<ul>";
    string otherGroup = "<ul>";
    foreach (string grp in myGroupsMem)
    {
        //BulletedListMyGroups.Items.Add(grp);

        glList = glList + "<li>" + grp + "</li>";
        if (allGroups.Contains(grp))
        {
            DropDownListMyGroups.Items.Add(grp);
            openlList = openlList + "<li>" + grp + "</li>";
        }
        else 
        {
            otherGroup = otherGroup + "<li>" + grp + "</li>";
        }
    }

    glList = glList + "</ul>";
    openlList = openlList + "</ul>";
    otherGroup = otherGroup + "</ul>";
    LabelOtherGrp.Text = otherGroup;
    LabelOpenGrp.Text = openlList;

    // LabelMyGroup.Text = glList;

    foreach (string emailGroup in allGroups)
    {
        if (!myGroupsMem.Contains(emailGroup))
        {
            DropDownListOpenGroups.Items.Add(emailGroup);
        }
    }

}
```

This is code which run when a page reload.

The issue is : When I click on Remove Button or Add Button, it run the code to add or remove user from selected group. when page reload after clicking on button.  The Group membership labels. and Dropdown box is not updating with code :(

Comment: can you show your Code how you are Adding or removing?

Comment: can you show your Code how you are Adding or removing?

Comment: Make your question more clear . Specify the code  / how u submit the data  .

Comment: On postback ( in corresponding click events) re fetch the data and show . When you click refresh a reload is happening and page is fetched again

Comment: Have you checked whether you grapped the correct data on postback??

Comment: I have updated the code on page load too_cool

Comment: How can we check if we grab the correc data on page load @Midhun

Comment: Dear @RohithNair , how can we reload the page then? Thanks

Comment: @Aman Dhally,can u add markup (design code) also.

Comment: @AmanDhally it is just the order of events which causing confusion IMO. Page_Load is called first and then control events(click, change etc). So on add/delete you need to rebind the items

Comment: @RohithNair, thanks, you mean to say, I need to add the click events buttons before Page_load, need to re-order it?

Comment: @Aman Move out the databind logic  to a function and call function at the end of click event as well. Then you can reuse the function in page load and put logic to bind in page load only of its not postback because you might be rebinding unnecessarily in page load

Comment: @RohithNair I tried as you suggested, and i move the data to another method and it stil not updating the page... :(

Comment: Just to add, when I run this page locally using VS2013 (F5), it works as expected, but when I publish it, then it start causing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your scenario like this, you're having two Drop down. One is full of records and the items can be select. Once items are selected, user will submit the button then records will save into database/xml. Later you're retrieving the items from db/xml and showing that in second Drop down.

Now you're issue is that the records are not showing in second Drop down after clicking the submit button,

If it so, you have two options.

1) You can pull your records as soon as insert things made into db.
2) You can pull your records in Page load itself as I mentioned below,

```
If(Postback) // Or If(PostBack == true)
{
  // Pull your records and display in Drop down.
}
```

Comment: Hi gKrishy, I have already tried this, but this is not working for me :( ,

Comment: Just to add, when I run this page locally using VS2013 (F5), it works as expected, but when I publish it, then it start causing this issue.

Comment: @gkrishy, the issue, is, I have a webpage,  when user open it, it shows the list of groups, he is a member of, then there are two drop down. 1 dropdown is showing the list of all his group membership and a button to remove it, the second drop down shows the various list of groups, whose the user can add to himself with a add button,. Now the problem is, whenever user add or remove him self, the main page is in updating with update info, until we refresh it  manually. :(

Comment: @AmanDhally Consider I'm having 'Singers' in my list of groups and I want to add 'Hollywood' to my list. For this, I need to choose Hollywood from second drop down, later I need to click on Add button. Now your issue, after clicking of Add button also, Hollywood is not adding in my list of groups(first drop down) ?

Comment: @gkrishy Yup, that was the issue :( . But it is resolved now, Thanks a ton for you Time and Help.

Answer (score 0):

It is just the order of events which causing confusion IMO. Page_Load is called first and then control events(click, change etc). So on add/delete you need to rebind the items.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Move out the data bind logic to a function and call function at the end of click event as well. Then you can reuse the function in page load and put logic to bind in page load only of its not postback because you might be rebinding unnecessarily in page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
      if(!IsPostBack)
    {
       DataBindLogic();
    }
    }

    private void DataBindLogic()
    {
      /*Put databind code here */
    }

    protected void RemoveBtn_Click(Object sender,Eventargs args)
    {
      /*Do db update */
      DataBindLogic();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Rohit , I have tried the above solution and the result is the same :( . it still not updating page :*(

Comment: Just to add, when I run this page locally using VS2013 (F5), it works as expected, but when I publish it, then it start causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot everyone and and each of you for your time and help and energy, thanks a ton.

The issue is resolved, I have added another lines of code in the Postback, which checks the action of the User.

For example, if used Remove from the Group,

- Then get the name of the Group and use action REMOVE
- Then Update the DropDown box and Current membership box.

I did the same for the add group too, and it resolved the issue for me.

Thanks again , and whishing you a great day ahead.

Regards and Best wishes
Aman